# Chrome extension...execute CSS from JS?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension where I want to make all the images on a page spin using CSS keyframe animation, but I also want it to toggle on/off using JS. I've already figured out how to toggle on and off, but how should I execute the CSS from the JS? All I can think of is to just find all images, and add the `.animation` class, but it doesn't seem to work.

**manifest.JSON**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "SPINS",
  "description": "SPINS",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": { },

  "icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
           "48": "icon48.png",
          "128": "icon128.png" },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": 
    [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "css": [ "spin.css"],
      "js": [ "content.js"]
      }],



  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

**background.JS**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{});
});
```

**content.JS**

```
var toggle = false;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function() {
  toggle = !toggle;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'), function(el) {
    el.addClass("animation");
  });
});
```

**spin.CSS**

```
@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

.animation {
    animation: 40s spin infinite linear;
}
```

Comment: Why use `Array.prototype.forEach.call()` ? Wouldn't a simple `document.getElementsByTagName()` and for loop do the trick?

Comment: @AndrueAnderson Maybe there's a strong preference for functional-style `forEach` over `for (;;)` loop

Comment: @ooohfff, You need to explain better what you mean by "execute CSS".

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
el.addClass("animation");
```

with

```
el.className = el.className + " animation";
```